# How do I "limit" the creation of an element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I press the 'Create Question' button, I create an element called "question" class. I create a new element divi called "selection" class with "Create Stylish" button in "Question" class. I want that only 5 divs can be produced from each "selection" class under each "question" class. How do I get that?

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="asd"></div>
  <button onclick="create()" id="create" class="btn btn-primary">Soru oluştur</button><br /><br /><button class="btn btn-dark col-md-2 pull-right" style="text-align:center" onclick="list()">Liste</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success col-md-4 offset-4" style="text-align:center" style="position: static" id="btn" onclick="save()">Kaydet</button>
</div>
<script>
  function create() {
    $("<div class='question container' id='question'" + "style='background-color:lavender;border:solid 15px darkcyan;" + " height:500px; border-radius:32px'><div class='input-group' " + "style='margin-top:10px'><input type='text' placeholder='Soru Gir...' class='form-control'/> " +
        "&nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger deletequestion' >Sil</button>" + "&nbsp; &nbsp;" + "<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='createSelection(this)'>Şık Ekle</button></div></div></br>")
      .insertBefore("#btn");
  }

  function createSelection(x) {
    $(x).closest('.question').first('.selection').append(
      "<div class='input-group selection' style='margin-top:10px' id='selection'>" + "<input type='text' id='clean' placeholder='Şık Gir...' class='form-control'/> " + "&nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger deleteselection'>Şıkı Sil</button>" + & nbsp; & nbsp; < button class = 'btn btn-success'
      onclick = 'clean()' > Temizle < /button></div > ");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note you can't repeat id's in a page...they are unique by definition

Comment: @charlietfl

I did not understand. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: For example `id='question'` can only exist once in page

Comment: @charlietfl
Not id. I ask in class. You're confused because ID is the same. But the class name is the same. Will you look again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to count how many `.selection` descendants the closest `.question` element has, then only append another `.selection` div if the number is less than 5.

```
function createSelection(x) {
  if ($(x).closest('.question').find('.selection').length < 5) {
    $(x).closest('.question').first('.selection').append("<div class='input-group selection' style='margin-top:10px' id='selection'>" + "<input type='text' id='clean' placeholder='Şık Gir...' class='form-control'/> " + "&nbsp; &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger deleteselection'>Şıkı Sil</button>" + "& nbsp; & nbsp; < button class = 'btn btn-success' onclick = 'clean()' > Temizle < /button></div > ");
  }
}
```

Be aware that there are some issues with your current code; notably, you are creating multiple elements with the same id's. You cannot repeat id's in a page. Remove `id='selection'` from the `.selection` div's to avoid future problems.

[Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/EZVZIYsENYPmQdrw6kzN/)

Comment: Thank you so much :)
Now what exactly have you done here?
You checked to see if 5 of the 'selection' classes near the 'question' class were created. If it was less than 5, you asked him to create it. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. I select the closest element with class `question`, then count how many of its descendants have the class `selection`. Only if there are less than five is a new `selection`-classed element created.

Comment: I want to ask you something else. I am deleting the element with the 'Question' class. I want to move the element after the deleted element to the location of the deleted element. If I don't do this, there are gaps on the page. How do I copy the deleted item's position before it was deleted, transfer it to the position of the next element after the deleted item, and save it to the location of the deleted item?

Comment: Removing elements from the DOM will automatically reflow the document. You should not need to programmatically assign positions to each element. You can post a new question if there is an issue.